# How can I upload mp3 files from angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I am new to angular. I need some help, I want to "upload" mp3 files from my angular app. In fact, I want to send mp3 files to backend and then save in my local database. Any suggestion to do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what you tried so far. Please refer [How to Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) when you as a question. Happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need a file upload using angular and https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/ is good. After clicking on the link there you will get a demo also there you can test your mp3 upload functionality